# reseed a column

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a tinyint column and it's autoincrement.
How can I set it to start from 0 instead of 1.
I use: DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, 0)
but when I insert a record it starts from 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get 0 as next identity value if the table never has contained any rows since it was created or if you removed all rows with truncate otherwise you will get seedvalue+1.

Described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

This will set next identity to 0

```
truncate table MyTable
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, 0)
```

If you change datatype from tinyint to smallint you can reseed to -1 and will get 0 when you do next insert.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, -1)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my table has foreign key, what can I do now?

Comment: You can also use delete and then reseed to -1. `delete from MyTable` and then `
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, -1)`

Comment: @Raymond Updated answer. If you can change datatype to smallint you can reseed to -1.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [Truncate the table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx) to remove all data then you must ensure that you have the column definition like this:

```
Create Table YourTable
(
YourColumn TinyInt Identity(0,1)
...
...
)
```

Then run `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, 0)`

The next row you insert will have a value of 0